# Android SSO in subactivity doesn't call OnComplete

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, single-sign-on, android-activity

I have something like a menu Activity (let's call it activity 1) where the user presses a button and another Activity (let's call it activity 2) gets started. I want to use Facebook SSO in activity 2.

The code in activity 1 to start activity 2 is as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ViewDomanda.class);
startActivity(i);
```

so far, so good... ViewDomanda (i.e. activity 2 gets started ok).
Relevant code of `ViewDomanda.java`is:

```
public class ViewDomanda extends Activity {
      private Facebook qqFacebook;
      private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.domanda);


            this.qqFacebook = new Facebook(MY_APP_ID);

        /*
         * Get existing access_token if any
         */
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        Log.i("access_token",String.valueOf(access_token));

        if(access_token != null) {
            this.qqFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires != 0) {
            this.qqFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        /*
         * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
         */
        if(!this.qqFacebook.isSessionValid()) {

            this.qqFacebook.authorize((Activity)this, new String[] {},
                     new DialogListener() {
                  public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", qqFacebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", qqFacebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                    Log.i("onComplete","done");
                  }

                  public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

                  public void onError(DialogError e) {}

                  public void onCancel() {}
                });
        }
}
```

and then I have the usual:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            this.qqFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

I am logged in Facebook app, so the authorize method just ask me to give permissions to the FB app.

Problems are:

1. After giving permissions to FB app, activity 2 is suddenly closed and activity 1 comes back instead.
2. Even worse, the OnComplete method of the DialogListener does not gets called, and the Android app is not authorized while my FB users gets the FB apps installed.

I thought I had followed exactly what's in the tutorial, but surely I am missing something.
Any help will be highly appreciated.